# ecto / mute log for a given query

Tags: elixir, ecto

Ecto logging customization is possible app-wide; but i was wondering if an option exists to mute logs only for specific queries

Having many batches occurring in the background with this kind of query; returning large logs :

```
Repo.insert_all(
  ModelName,
  dataset,
  on_conflict: :replace_all,
  conflict_target: [:col1, :col2]
)
```

Was looking to mute those specifically in order not to pollute the iex console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Repo.insert_all(
  ModelName,
  dataset,
  on_conflict: :replace_all,
  conflict_target: [:col1, :col2],
  log: false
)
```

That should work.

More info in the docs [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-shared-options).